# Save a text file to a remote network shared folder like https://

Tags: c#, webdav

My client provides a network shared folder in the format of https://xxxx with user name and pwd. I need to write a console application to put a text file there. Is there any .Net class or library available? I prefer open source lib if available.

By the way, I can see the shared folder from Windows File Explorer: My Computer->My Network Places

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at

HTTP put - that's the first thing that came to mind.  An example can be seen here::

http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/HTTPputwithusernameandpassword.htm

Comment: It looks like to send a text stream to remote URL but it does not provide a file name on remote side. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it might be a webdav server. you can take a look at this question here if it helps: [Open source library in c# to communicate with a WebDAV server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84088/open-source-library-in-c-to-communicate-with-a-webdav-server)

Answer (score 0):

You need a command line tool to POST a file to some URL, right? What about

```
>curl --data-binary /usr/xzy/testfile -u user:passwd https://xxx
```

In essence [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) is a tool that allows to reproduce literally any HTTP request that you might possibly need to send. However, it's a unix/linux tool and you might need [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to run it on a Windows machine.

On a linux environment your task might be reduced to writing a UI that triggers curl as external command.

If for nothing else, curl might be a great debugging/testing tool for your developement.

Comment: how about to get file list from the url site? Is this possible?

Comment: If that's equivalent to a HTTP GET on yyy.example.com then you just use "curl <URL>".